# How are pandas dataframes implemented? Can we implement similar dataframes with some customizations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to only some of the functionalities of Pandas dataframe and need to remove others or restrict users from using them. So, I am planning to write my own dataframe class which would only have a subset of methods of Pandas dataframes.

Comment: does info on subclassing pandas.DataFrame help? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures

Comment: i would suggest you to take your time, and write your framework without any help. this may take some time, but surely a lot learning, secondly if you want to copy the pandas, you can look into git repo of pandas!

Comment: Not happening. Years of man hours have gone into pandas, you're not going to get anywhere reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I agree to your point of reinventing the wheel. But is there a way I could only write a subset of dataframe functionalities. Like implementing only Slicing(limited) but not plotting or other functions. It would be helpful if you provide some resources to study.

Comment: @smundlay Thank you. I will go through it. Although when I subclass I will need to override many methods, as I just don't need all of them.  But it is a bit tedious. I need to learn some implementation myself. from learning point of view, can u suggest some resources?

Comment: @SangramGaikwad, so you know that pandas is built on top of numPy. I would start there (here is the main repo: https://github.com/numpy/numpy). this way, you can work from the ground up. Since I don't know what methods you want to override for what reason, it's hard to help further right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for pandas DataFrame object can be found [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L236-L6142).

Theoretically you could clone the repository and re-write sections of it.  However, it's not a simple object and this may take a decent amount of reading into the code to understand how it works.

For example: pandas describes the dataframe object as a

> Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data
>       structure with labeled axes (rows and columns). Arithmetic operations
>       align on both row and column labels. Can be thought of as a dict-like
>       container for Series objects.