# What is a dataframe from programming point of view?

Tags: dataframe, data-science, computer-science

Several data-science packages, e.g. Python's Pandas, have a "dataframe" around which all other functionality are based. What exactly is a dataframe from programming point of view?

Comment: My observation has been that Panda's DataFrame resembles an in-core relational table.  It has named, typed columns, selection and join operations, reduction operations.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually an object.
The source code for Pandas DataFrame object can be found [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L236-L6142)!

Pandas describes the DataFrame object as:

> Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data structure with labeled axes (rows and columns). Arithmetic operations align on both row and column labels. Can be thought of as a dict-like container for Series objects.

This block-quote has been referred from: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L236-L6142

Comment: Thanks to Elijah Moreau-Arnott. Original answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130691/how-are-pandas-dataframes-implemented-can-we-implement-similar-dataframes-with

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).